# Apache spark : Number of tasks less than the number of partitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

As per my understanding of Apache Spark, the number of tasks created is equal to the number of partitions. but when I did a df.count() (Narrow transformation) the tasks created where less than the number of partitions. I am using community version of databricks.

[image: SPARK UI]

[image: DF creation]

Tried with different number of partitions but experienced the same issue.

Comment: AQE is set  to on?

Comment: Nope. I thought it might have been the reason and have explicitly set it to false              

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", false)